# Detect change of fontstyle in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

When a cell value is changed in excel the sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) is fired.
How can I detect when the fontstyle of a cell in Excel is changed?
The sub Worksheet_Change  is not fired when the fontstyle changes.

For example:
Cell A1   value is nothing
Cell A1   value is changed to  HALLO WORLD
The sub Worksheet_Change is fired

Cell A1   fontstyle is changed to strikethrough
The sub Worksheet_Change is not fired

How can I detect in VBA that the fontstyle is changed from normal to strikethrough

I have this in Excel:
[excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hgHr.png)

And this is my VBA-code so far, which doesn't work.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Fstrikethrough As Boolean
Dim Fbold As Boolean


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Fstrikethrough = Target.Font.Strikethrough
    Fbold = Target.Font.Bold
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Font.Strikethrough <> Fstrikethrough Then
        MsgBox ("strikethrough is changed")
        Fstrikethrough = Target.Font.Strikethrough
    End If
    If Target.Font.Bold <> Fbold Then
        MsgBox ("bold is changed")
        Fbold = Target.Font.Bold
    End If
End Sub
```

For example when I change cell A2 to strikethrough, I want the msgbox appear.

Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't any events to capture font sytle change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such event trigger

You can have a "sort of" by placing this code in the relevant worksheet code pane

```
Option Explicit

Dim lastStrikeThrough As String
Dim lastRng As Range
    
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not lastRng Is Nothing Then
        If lastStrikeThrough <> lastRng.Font.Strikethrough Then
            MsgBox "Cell '" & lastRng.Address(False, False) & "' font changed" _
                   & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbTab & "from Strikethrough='" & lastStrikeThrough & "'" _
                   & vbCrLf & vbTab & "to Strikethrough='" & lastRng.Font.Strikethrough & "'"
        End If
    End If
        Set lastRng = Target
        lastStrikeThrough = Target.Font.Strikethrough
    
End Sub
```

The "sort of" is in that the user is warned right after the font change cell is abandoned

It only covers the `Font.Strikethrough` change and assumes you're dealing with a one cell range only.
The code can be tweaked to deal with more `Font` properties change and multicells ranges

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.
I added to my question an example and the code I have so far.
Can you please have a look on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try using my code and watch what happens